# Byobu (tmux backend) after copying text in scrollback mode automatically quits scrollback mode

Tags: tmux, byobu, iterm2

To clarify, "automatically quits scrollback" mode means byobu goes into normal mode and jumps to the bottom, and I can't just go back to the point I previously scrolled up to.

I am also using iterm2 and use mouse (set in .tmux.conf) to enter scrollback mode, not sure how it affects the configurations.